# AdMob orientation problem in Android

Tags: android, layout, admob

My application integrates with [AdMob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdMob) ads. When I change the orientation it should fit the screen depending on orientation. In portrait mode it is working fine, but when I changed to landscape  mode the ad size I am getting in portrait mode is the same size of the ad displayed in landscape mode.

I am adding the following in layout page.

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
   myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
   myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
/>
```

Comment: I think its problem of AdMob and we (as developers) can do nothing with that except two things (As I saw on AdMod site, max size of this view is 320x59 px nomore) : 
1) ask AdMod developers to fix that; 
2) decompile AdMob jar file and change this behaviour :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seem that the answer here is from admob:

http://groups.google.com/group/admob-publisher-discuss/browse_thread/thread/17451c55258de1ec?pli=1

> Unfortunately we don't support 480 dip
>   wide ads at this time.  We have 
>   unified the presentation of our ads
>   across the network, and we have  not
>   extended our ad formats to a 480
>   pixels wide format at this time.  We
>   hope to add support for them soon. 
>   Our SDK is built in such a way  that
>   when we introduce the wider ad unit
>   for landscape phones and  other larger
>   screens,  the new ads will already be
>   supported and you  will not need to
>   update to a new SDK.

So unfortunately, seem impossible to stretch the ads.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue but didn't fix it yet.

I was thinking of adding Admob's `AdView` inside a `LinearLayout` with the exact same `backgroundColor`.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/admob_stuff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000">

  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/ad"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
  myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
  myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great idea. A simple easy fix that looks a whole lot better already than having a black ad and a white background, e.g.